GCC "labels as values" – intended usage
I recently heard about the Labels as Values extension to C/C++ in GCC and other compilers.  I was thinking about how I'd use that to write a threaded interpreter (where a virtual machine program is defined by chaining together addresses of real machine code blocks).
Of course, I can only goto a label from inside the function where the label is defined, but I still want to use the label values outside that scope; for instance, when I'm compiling or storing VM code rather than executing it.  I am picturing an interpreter as something like this:
#include <stdio.h>

void interpret (void **prog) {
    void **pc = prog;
    goto **pc;
    foo: printf("Foo"); goto nextword;
    bar: printf("Bar"); goto nextword;
    nextword:
        if (*(++pc) != STOP) {
            printf(" ");
            goto **pc;
        } else printf (".\n");
    stop: return;
}

// definition of VM instructions:
void *FOO=&&foo, *BAR=&&bar, *STOP=&&stop;

int main (int argc, char **argv) {
    // a real interpreter would generate this from source code:
    void *prog[] = {FOO, BAR, FOO, BAR, BAR, FOO, STOP};
    interpret(prog);
    return 0;
}

I.E., I want the label addresses as global constants. But the example above won't compile, because the extension doesn't allow labels-as-values outside of a function body, and labels in C have function scope anyway.
I could make the interpret() function with a special "setup" mode, e.g. if I pass NULL, it initialises the globals and returns immediately.  I guess I could live with that, but it seems kludgey.
Several examples I've seen store the label addresses in a static array within the function and then pass the program as a list of integer indices into that array.  But that adds an additional fetch operation to every VM instruction at runtime; doesn't that run counter to the whole purpose of this extension?
Is there something I am missing?  Or, if this is a feature request, is there a reason why something like my example couldn't be implemented?

Whatever you're trying to do, it feels horrible. All your code is stuffed into one function so you can actually use that goto thing, and if you're simply calling other functions then why not use function pointers from the beginning and skip that rubbish proprietary unportable compiler feature. And yes, I only understood half of what you're doing, if at all. Just go on with it and see for yourself whether it works out for you or not.

@ChristianStieber: A quick test with clang shows that at least on some ARM platforms, it's possible to run multiple independent state machines in round-robin fashion within a function quite efficiently if the code for each state machine sets its associated address to the label it should run next, and then jumps to the next state machines address.  There are limits to how much one could do before register values would have to be spilled to stack, but in some cases this kind of trick may allow things be kept in registers while bouncing between state machines, netting a major speedup.

You would use setjmp and longjmp to do a goto outside of the scope of the label.

@ChristianStieber: Such techniques are ugly, and I wouldn't trust clang any further than I could throw it, but it does seem to handle this technique well enough that it could offer a 2:1 speedup in some rare--but still useful--types of code (e.g. on a Raspberry Pi Pico, if one core would be spending its whole existence emulating two peripherals in ways that barely meet timing requirements even with the speedup).

I believe the ocaml bytecode interpreter uses this extension if you want an example of it in use

It would be difficult to implement it because of inlining.
If the address of a label is taken in a static initializer, GCC disables inlining of that function entirely. This is because the position of the code physically changes when the function is inlined, so the value of the static variable would be wrong when it is, e.g.:
void f() {
    goto *&&x;
    x: return;
}

void g() {
    f();  // If f is inlined: `&&x` would be somewhere in `g()`
}

void h() {
    f();  // `&&x` if `f()` is inlined here would be different
}

But if you allow it to be used in a static initializer outside of the function, you never know if the address is taken into another translation unit:
// TU 1
inline int f(void* p) {
    goto *p;
    a: return 1;
    b: return 2;
}

int h(void* p) { return f(p); }  // f is inlined into h

// TU 2
inline int f(void* p) {
    goto *p;
    a: return 1;
    b: return 2;
}
static void* A = &&a;
int h(void* p);
int g() {
    h(A);  // This would be the address inside `f`, which doesn't exist in TU1 and not an expected value of the inlined function.
}

And it's even more difficult in C because of how inline functions work in C. I'm sure GCC also makes a bunch of reachability optimizations, so allowing this would mean that it must assume all computed gotos with unknown values could goto any label so it couldn't optimize out any labels at all.

If you switch to computed goto with indices:
enum instruction {
    FOO, BAR, STOP
};

void interpret_computed_goto(enum instruction *pc) {
    static void* indices[] = { &&foo, &&bar, &&stop };
    goto *indices[*pc];
    foo: printf("Foo"); goto nextword;
    bar: printf("Bar"); goto nextword;
    nextword:
        if (*(++pc) != STOP) {
            printf(" ");
            goto *indices[*pc];
        } else printf (".\n");
    stop: return;
}

int main (int argc, char **argv) {
    enum instruction prog[] = {FOO, BAR, FOO, BAR, BAR, FOO, STOP};
    interpret_computed_goto(prog);
}

... This can usually be converted into a switch pretty easily:
void interpret_switch_direct(enum instruction *pc) {
    // goto *indices[*pc] -> switch (pc)
    start:
    switch (*pc) {
    // labels -> cases
    case FOO: printf("Foo"); goto nextword;
    case BAR: printf("Bar"); goto nextword;
    nextword:
        if (*(++pc) != STOP) {
            printf(" ");
            // Second computed goto: reroute to original switch
            goto start;
        } else printf (".\n");
    case STOP: return;
    }
}

This might be able to be done mechanically, but rewriting it from scratch gets something more readable:
void interpret_switch(enum instruction *pc) {
    if (*pc == STOP) return;
    while (1) {
        switch (*pc++) {
        case FOO: printf("Foo"); break;
        case BAR: printf("Bar"); break;
        case STOP: printf (".\n"); return;
        }
        if (*pc != STOP) printf(" ");
    }
}

You'll find that switch-case like this is implemented as-if there was a large table of addresses of labels and then a computed goto with the appropriate address. (It doesn't happen with this example because there aren't enough cases, but if you add a few more you can see the table in the generated assembly).
Worrying about indexing into a table is probably a premature optimization. If that does end up being an issue, on x86 at least, goto *p is basically the same as return ((return_type(*)(void)) p)(), so you might want to switch to functions instead of labels.
